# How to install Classifychars and other OpenAlr Utilites in windows?

Tags: python, openalpr

I downloaded source files from

> https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/releases

now in `src/misc_utilities` I can see `classifychar.cpp` but it requires:

> include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
>
> include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

so I downloaded `OpenCV2` source but inside it I cant find `highgui/highgui.hpp`
instead its in `\modules\highgui\include\opencv2` so I changed it its absolute path. Now I cant find `utility.h` and `support/ut8f.h`